# libgdx android render for two views simultaneously

Tags: android, casting, libgdx, chromecast, glsurfaceview

I am developing an android app for the fresh Google Cast API for remote display
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

I have used libgdx for rendering my objects on the device android screen. 
That worked fine.

Now I want to add functionality to my app: render some other objects to another view that I can pass to the layout of remote screen.

I have tried as in the remote display example, first I created an AndroidGraphic and pass this to the setRender function because AndroidGraphic is implementing Renderer interface:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.first_screen_layout);

        firstScreenSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        firstScreenSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        // Allow UI elements above this surface; used for text overlay
        firstScreenSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        firstScreenSurfaceView.setRenderer((AndroidGraphics) mGraphics);
```

If i run this alone, this is working fine - objects are rendered by libgdx to the remote screen. But if I start my Activity that renders via libgdx and I also start the renderer in the service as described above, one screen freezes at the begin, the other screen in my case remote screen (TV connected via Chromecast) is rendering the view right.

My question is now: is it possible to render for two views at the same time with libgx android backend? Or are they using shared resources that this is not possible?

Because if i run my activity on device render via libgdx and run the CubeRender at the same time, they are both working well simultaneously. So I think my problem is by libgdx and shared resources.

Comment: Libgdx doesn't support this. It uses some static references to the graphics surfaces (`Gdx.graphics` and `Gdx.gl`) and so only is able to support one. I think this makes it unlikely that it will support more than one in the future because it would break so much code.

Comment: Okay, I supposed there would some problems. Is it possible to set those static references manually? I also tried that to change and set that static references manually: I mutually excluded the render function, so only one of my two GL threads accessed the render function and there I set the `Gdx.graphics Gdx.gl` manually, but that also doesn't work for me, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't know. Would have to read through a lot of the libgdx source code to see where things might go wrong.